# ESLint looking for config in src file (configured in default way)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I installed eslint-loader and eslint loaders as dependencies through NPM.  Following an online guide, I put it in my module.exports.  Strangely, although I know after research that eslint looks for the default configuration file if one is not provided, I get the following build error.

> ERROR in ./src/index.js
>   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>   Error: No ESLint configuration found in C:\Users\lukea\Local Sites\molehills-to-mountains\app\public\wp-content\themes\auberge-child\src.

Here is the eslint object in my module.exports

```
    {
            test: /\.js$/,
            enforce: "pre",
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "eslint-loader",
    },
```

There is a strong chance more information will be needed, but as I have a large codebase, I will provide it based on feedback.  Thanks Stack.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using these version

```
"eslint": "^5.0.0",
"eslint-loader": "2.0.0"
```

In my .eslintrc file

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true,
      "modules": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  },
  "plugins": ["react"],
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"],
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": [2, "never"],
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-console": "off",
    "no-debugger": "off",
    "no-unexpected-multiline": "warn",
    "no-alert": "off",
    "comma-spacing": [2, { "before": false, "after": true }]
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "pragma": "React",
      "version": "15.6.1"
    }
  },
  "globals": {
    "Promise": true,
    "alert": true,
    "global": true,
    "window": true,
    "document": true,
    "process": true,
    "module": true,
    "console": true,
    "sessionStorage": true,
    "localStorage": true
  }
}
```

Then my webpack

```
module: {
    rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
                'style-loader',
                MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                {
                    loader: "css-loader",
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                        sourceMap: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: "sass-loader"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: ["babel-loader", "eslint-loader"] // here
        },
        {
            test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i,
            loader: "file-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(woff|ttf|otf|eot|woff2|svg)$/i,
            loader: "file-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```